# How to modify the SOAP envelope in Python Suds?

Tags: python, soap, sharepoint-2007, suds

I am using Python Suds to use the Web Service provided by Sharepoint 2007.
Specifically I want to use the UpdateListItems provided by the Lists.aspx service.

As mentioned in the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.updatelistitems%28v=office.12%29.aspx) at msdn, I am creating the xml parameter. But it throws me a `SoapServerException`. The traceback isnt any use because Sharepoint 2007 blindly throws the exception without giving any details.

I also followed the guidelines [here](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/SharepointArticle) at the Suds docs given for the UpdateListItems example. But to no use. I think the problem is that the XML that Suds is making for me is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <ns0:Body>
      <ns1:UpdateListItems>
         <ns1:listName>MyDocuments</ns1:listName>
         <ns0:updates>
            <Batch OnError="Continue" ListVersion="1">
               <Method ID="1" Cmd="Delete">
                  <Field Name="ID">7</Field>
                  <Field Name="FieldRef">http://win2003/sharepoint_site/MyDocuments/aal.txt</Field>
               </Method>
            </Batch>
         </ns0:updates>
      </ns1:UpdateListItems>
   </ns0:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

But the example at suds docs looks like this:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns0:UpdateListItems>
         <ns0:listName>MySchedule</ns0:listName>
         <Batch OnError="Continue" ListVersion="1">
            <Method ID="1" Cmd="New">
               <Field Name="ID">New</Field>
               <Field Name="Title">Toasting</Field>
               <Field Name="EndDate">2009-03-07 18:00:00</Field>
               <Field Name="EventDate">2009-03-07 17:00:00</Field>
               <Field Name="Location">Everywhere</Field>
               <Field Name="Description">Stuff!</Field>
            </Method>
         </Batch>
      </ns0:UpdateListItems>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I think the problem is the element inside Body. The example says `ns0` while I get ns1`.

So I tried to use Plugins, as suggested by dusan in this question here:

[python suds wrong namespace prefix in SOAP request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10207167/python-suds-wrong-namespace-prefix-in-soap-request)

So I am using `marshalled()` method and my code looks like this:

```
class UpdatePlugin(MessagePlugin):
    def marshalled(self, context):
        body = context.envelope.getChild("Body")
        updateListItems = body[0]
        listName = body[1]
        updateListItems.setPrefix("ns0")
        listName.setPrefix("ns0")
```

However the last line above gives the following Error:

```
ERROR:suds.plugin:'NoneType' object has no attribute 'setPrefix'
```

So `body` is `None` itself. Clearly I am doing something wrong. Help me please.

Answer (score 1):

`<ns0:updates>` should be `<ns1:updates>`, and try `client.options.prettyxml = True` (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21395165/819417)) because Suds is terribly buggy and [unmaintained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038226/suds-is-not-reusing-cached-wsdls-and-xsds-although-i-expect-it-to).